# Determination severity of message/growl in p:growl

Tags: jsf, primefaces, exception, growl

I have following code in my backing bean:

```
try {
    contractService.create(selectedContract);
    conversation.end();
    return "search?faces-redirect=true";
} catch (ActiveContractExistsException e) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, e.getMessage()));
    return null;
}
```

In jsf:

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" closable="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
```

and

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{contractView.update}" update="growl"/>
```

As a result I'm getting:

[image]

Like you can see this is far from `SEVERITY_ERROR`. But the most interesting part is when my code is following (adding message outside the `catch` block):

```
    try {
        contractService.create(selectedContract);
        conversation.end();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Some message"));
        return "search?faces-redirect=true";
    } catch (ActiveContractExistsException e) {
        //FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        //context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Some message"/*e.getMessage()*/));
        return null;
    }
```

then all fine:

[image]

How can I set `SEVERITY_ERROR` level to my message while handling exception?

Comment: It's hard to understand the last example works. FacesMessages do not survive a PRG (which the `?faces-redirect=true` does). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685633/how-to-show-faces-message-in-the-redirected-page.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for the responce, I've already solve my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling service layer exception in Java EE frontend method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853167/handling-service-layer-exception-in-java-ee-frontend-method)

Answer (score 0):

My problem relates with EE container. In case I'm not extended from EJBException they wrapping automatically, therefore block `catch` doesn't executing. There are two ways to solve my problem:

1. Extend my custom exception from EJBException
2. Add `@ApplicationException` annotation to my class exception