# Access FacesContext in interceptor when having distributed system

Tags: jsf, ejb, interceptor, distributed-system

I would like to know if there is a way to access http request parameters like (RemoteHost,LocalPort,...etc) or FacesContext in business layer for example (ejb or interceptor) but for distributed system  .

so the scenario is I have an interceptor that works when jsf talk to controller (managedBean) then to ejb method , inside Interceptor when I tried to get

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
```

for distributed system I got null .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the service layer not supposed to be interested in view layer specific APIs. It violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and makes the service layer unreusable on other view layers (e.g. JAX-RS, Servlets/JSP, etc).

Instead, let the view pass the information of interest as plain method arguments.

#### See also:

- [JSF Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011392/jsf-service-layer)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,
 but even at client side using InitialContext I couldn pass contextual data and use it in Interceptor InvocationContext.getContextData() ? 

I dont want to go over all system and send parameters that I need in interceptor when calling ejb method .